# ASMX InvalidOperationException being thrown when setting up sqlconnection to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx

A bit of a legacy development, however, this is our final push until we start on a new project using newer technologies.

As the title states, this is an asmx webservice that I am trying to debug. It has a WPF interface for the user. The asmx webservice provides this interface with data (a datagrid and few dropdowns) to allow us to export this data.

For the last few iterations, I need to create a new page that takes in a list of items from the webservice and make it the source for the grid/dropdowns and it is built. Though I am coming across issues running the webservice sql functionality and I have pinned it down to this line:

```
SqlConnection sql_dbConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLDataConn"].ToString());
```

As, it throws a null exception. What I have noticed that was strange was the service itself seemed to be throwing a bunch of errors as shown here:

[image]

IIS is configured and turned on as I can view it in a browser and attempt to invoke methods, but will fail.

This project (along with the other 4 in this project) are all on .NET 4.0

Comment: There is no connection string by that name in web.config

Comment: @Crowcoder in my web.config has it as:


    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="SQLDataConn" connectionString="DSN=SQL;pooling=true;UID=mike;PWD=mike" providerName="System.Data.Odbc"/>

Comment: The only way to get a null reference exception on that line is if the entry does not exist. If it does exist then you have mis-reported the problem.

Comment: You need to have connection string in web.config file of your web service and not only in your WPF application.

Comment: Do you have an app.config also in the project? For web.config settings, you should be using the WebConfigurationManager. The ConfigurationManager is meant for app.config files and WebConfigurationManager is meant for web.config files and has some features that work better for web application scenarios..

Answer (score 0):

Mark's comment was the correct solution.

Did not know that I was looking at the wrong configuration file.